# how do I apply the same function to the first column of all spreadsheets in the list R?

Tags: r

```r
setwd("C:\\Users\\Documents\spreadsheet")
n <- dir(pattern = ".csv")
files<- NULL
for (i in n) {  files[[i]] <- read.csv(i,sep = ";",header = T) }
 #class(files)
[1] "list"
```

I saved all spreadsheets in a mass to a list, how do I apply the same function to the first column of all spreadsheets in the list?

```r
library(forecast)
> map(files[,1],auto.arima)
Error in files[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions

> lapply(files[,1],auto.arima)
Error in files[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

All spreadsheets default to the same number of columns.

Comment: It seems like you edited your question to be a completely different question. The original question was about iterating through a list and applying a function. This new one is about fitting an arima model. I suggest undoing the edit and starting a new question, as you got a working answer for the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you lapply, it is iterating through every element of files. You want to apply a function on the first column of every element:

```
lapply(files,function(i)auto.arima(i[,1]))
```

Or:

```
library(purrr)
files %>% map(function(i)auto.arima(i[,1]))
```

You can further simplify it to (credit to @Adam):

```
files %>% map(~ auto.arima(.[,1]))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked to apply the function but is giving error in the forecast, I edited the post.

Comment: The beauty of `purrr` is that you do not need to create the anonymous function. Using just `map(~ auto.arima(.[,1]))` should work as well.

Comment: Arh yes Adam, thanks for pointing it out. I will edit my answer above.